# show a border in table rows when there is not td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with different number of `<td>`, something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
    </tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td>
    </tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I want to draw a line under every row, I tried these styles:

```
table{border-collapse: collapse;empty-cells: show;}
tbody{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
tr{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
td{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Lines are not reaching the end of the table, this is the expected result:

[image]

Is this possible using css only?

```css
table{border-collapse: collapse;empty-cells: show;}
tbody{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
tr{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
td{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
    </tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td>
    </tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr></tbody>
    <tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo element to create a long line and hide the overflow:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

td:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -100vw;
  ;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Just changed the display CSS property of the rows to block.
This isn't the perfect solution for dynamic data so I would suggest making a table out of divisions  and CSS.

I also suggest that you accept @Temani Afif answer since it is better than mine in the way that you can keep your table structure as well using the pseudo elements.

Comment: @TemaniAfif What? I clearly see that the table is still intact and it looks exactly like the question's expected result. As well as that, changing the display of the <tr> rows will not affect the table's functionality whatsoever unlike changing the display of the <td> tags.

Comment: it's because you have one character in each cell, check the link I sent where I added more content to the first cell. Add/remove display:block and see the result

Comment: @Ahm23 It absolutely will impact the tables functionality. Try to add a colspan on there and watch what happens.

Comment: Yes I've seen it

Comment: @TravisActon That's why I mentioned how it's only a proper solution for non-dynamic data and that TemaniAfif 's answer is better in many ways.